# Regex to allow all characters except repeats of a particular given character

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I've been fumbling with this for a bit and thought I'd put it up to the regex experts:

I want to match strings like this:

```
abc[abcde]fff
abcffasd
```

so I want to allow single brackets (e.g. `[` or `]`). However, I don't want to allow double brackets in sequence (e.g. `[[` or `]]`).

This means this string shouldn't pass the regex:

```
abc[abcde]fff[[gg]]
```

My best guess so far is based on [an example I found](http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/positive-examples-of-positive-and-negative-lookahead/), something like:

```
(?>[a-zA-Z\[\]']+)(?!\[\[)
```

However, this doesn't work (it matches even when double brackets are present), presumably because the brackets are contained in the first part as well.

Comment: Is `[]` (i.e. open then immediately close) allowed

Comment: @Dogbert - that's accepted, it's not double brace in a row. @joshb - that's accepted, it's not double brace in a row.

Comment: Incidentally, @nax posted an example which seems to work nicely for balanced pairs `^((\w+)|(\[\w+\]))+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like:

```
^(?:\[?[^\[]|\[$)*$
```

At each character, the pattern accepts an opening bracket followed by another character, or the end of the string.

Or a little more neatly, using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?:(?!\[\[).)*$
```

Here, the pattern will only match characters as long as it doesn't see two `[[` ahead.

Comment: Brilliant - cheers! I feel like I was tantalisingly close - learned a little about the use of `?:` today

Comment: @Kobi That last one doesn't match `abffa[]ssd]d]aa`. Also, the first one *does* match `abffa[]]ssd]d]aaa`.

Comment: @Graphain - `(?:...)` just avoids an unnecessary capture, `(...)` would have worked the same. Happy to help! By the way, if I may - the question was a little vague, which caused a few confused answerers (myself included)... The examples in the comments were missing from the question.

Comment: @Shibumi - that last one matches `abffa[]ssd]d]aa` for me. The last one does allow `]]`, which can be fixed by changing it to `^(?:(?!\[\[)(?!\]\]).)*$`

Comment: @Kobi That still matches if you have a double closing brace i.e. `]]`
EDIT: @Shibumi beat me to it.

Comment: @Kobi - A big thanks, it's of application in a lexer/parser I'm working on. Apologies for the question not being clearer, although I'm not sure which examples in comments were missing from the question?

Comment: @Shibumi - works for me - http://www.rubular.com/r/2gRarNMgOq . `]]` wasn't required in the question (I think), but you can do something like `^(?:(?!\[\[|\]\]).)*$` to disallow that as well. If you want something more flexible, you can also use `^(?:(?!([\[\]])\1).)*$`, so the inner `[]` can take any set of non-repeatable letters.

Comment: @Kobi So it does! Copy/paste error, I suppose. The ]] disallow was ... "However, I don't want to allow double brackets in sequence (e.g. [[ or ]])." What's really blowing my mind here is that you have a lookahead without anything before it followed by a `.`.

Answer (score 2):

**Not to be deterred!**

```
^(?:(?:[a-z]+)|(?:\](?!\]))|(?:\[(?!\[)))+$
```

I removed the only two or more thing. I removed the redundant character classes for only one characters. This seems to pass all test cases I can think of. Any string of characters containing only single `[` or `]`.

Let me know if it works for you!

---

I'm not sure I can answer this, but I'll post what I have as I'm going through it.

First, I have this which seems to match without the brackets. This is any letter not follwed by 2 or more of itself.

```
 ^(?:([a-z])(?!\1{2,}))+$
```

We can add the brackets into the character class and it will start matching brackets; but, obviously it will also allow them to follow the same rules as the letters (two together is valid). How do we separate the bracket behavior from the letter behavior?

```
 ^(?:([a-z\[\]])(?!\1{2,}))+$
```

This feels dirty, but seems to work. Looking at the other answer, I like that a lot better. Now to figure out why I didn't think of it.

```
^(?:(?:([a-z])(?!\1{2,}))|(?:[\]](?![\]]))|(?:[\[](?![\[])))+$
```

Also, for some reason I thought it was 1-2 of each character but only one of `[` and `]` so this is all worthless anyway :).

Comment: A big thanks and a +1 for your work here. This is pretty useful in its own right for thinking about regexes.

Comment: @Graphain You're welcome. I've got a long way to go with Regex, for sure :).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this negative lookahead:

```
$arr = array('abc[abcde]fff', 'abcffasd', 'abc[abcde]fff[[gg]]');
foreach ($arr as $str) {
   echo $str,' => ';
   $ret = preg_match('/^(?!.*?(\[\[)).+$/', $str, $m);
   echo "$ret\n";
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
abc[abcde]fff => 1
abcffasd => 1
abc[abcde]fff[[gg]] => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should allow all letters and brackets except two consecutive brackets (i.e. [], [[ or ]])

```
([a-zA-Z\[\]][a-zA-Z])+
```

EDIT: Sorry, this won't work for strings with odd length

Comment: This looks like a really easy answer (I can accept `[]` as invalid to get something this easy!). However, this wouldn't match `a` (i.e. single characters).

Comment: Fails to match `abffassddaa`. Won't work on odd-count strings.

Comment: @Graphain @Shibumi Yes, don't know how that one slipped through. Back to the drawing board for me